# Can I use scanner.skip() and scanner.hasNextLine() together?

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

Can I use .skip()  and .hasNextLine() together?

I'd like to have all nextline elements as long as they are not \r\n
For clarification, I have an excel document that does this:

I have an excel document that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUgu4.jpg

Which per my understanding reads like "1", "Day 1 \r\n Day2","4974","54","67","\n"
"2","Day3","56843","568","5496"

I have no control over this. It WILL come like this
In my program, I am making each row a different object.

I would like to read it like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Czjko.png

Which per my understanding reads like  "1", "Day 1 Day2","4974","54","67","\n" "2","Day3","56843","568","5496"

Originally, I was going to make one giant long string and then use the replace to replace all "\r\n" with a simple "   ", which solves my entire problem. But I do not know how to get the entire scanner object in one long string with all the line breaks etc. From there I could create a simple array of lines and then make my objects. but it keeps breaking on the first "\n" that is in the same cell.

So I had an idea, I don't need to do the entire replace. I can just SKIP the parts that contain "/r/n" and create the string so its only ending on "\n" NOT "\r\n".

I was hoping to do something like .skip("\r\n").hasNextLine() ie the following:

```
public static void readMe(Scanner fieldScan) {
    int row = 0;
    while (fieldScan.skip("\r\n").hasNextLine()){ 
        row++;
        String currentLine = fieldScan.skip("\r\n").nextLine();
        Field currentField = new Field(currentLine, row);
        if(!currentField.getRemove()) {
            fieldArrayList.add(currentField);
        }

    }
```

But this is not correct. And I do not understand why.

EDIT: What I want to do EXACTLY is count those as one row. it there is a line break, currently it is treating that as the current line.

so it would look like "1","Day 1" and thats all my information for that row.

I want all my information to be in one row. Instead of "Day 1" and "Day 2" being on two separate lines, I want them on one line, so it doesn't break up when I create objects

Comment: what do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: I need to find a way to either create one giant string from the scanner, including ALL the \r\n and \n in that string. or find a way to do a while loop through the scanner only on \n (NOT \r\n)